# PDOException Integrity constraint violation

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony

I'm working with Symfony2 and when I execute `doctrine:schema:update` I get the following error

> [PDOException]
>      SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update
>      a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`enquete`., CONSTRAINT `FK_880E0D76BF396750` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

Comment: can you give us some more information? E.g. code of `User`, mapping information, ect.?

Comment: please edit your question and include it there

Comment: i have a problem with  `doctrine:schema:update'
i get this error when i execute this command   `[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (enquete., CONSTRAINT FK_880E0D76BF396750 FOREIGN KEY
(id) REFERENCES user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE)'

Comment: once again, please edit your question instead of commenting.

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding the foreign key in that schema update? Do you have any data in your tables?
That error means that you have an enquete record in the database which has a reference to an user that dont exists in the user table.